# Solr fetch streaming expression doesn't fetch fields

Tags: solr

Ripped too much hair on this.

I have a streaming expression looking like:

```
fetch(
  myAlias,
  top(
    n=3,
  ....various expressions here
    sort="count(*) desc"
  ),
  fl="username", on="userid=userid", batchSize=3
)
```

which fails to fetch username field for the 1st result:

> {  "result-set":{   "docs":[{
> "userid":"123123",
> "count(*)":58}    ,{
> "userid":"123123123",
> "count(*)":32,
> "username":"Ayha"}    ,{
> "userid":"12432423321323",
> "count(*)":30,
> "username":"MEHM"}    ,{
> "EOF":true,
> "RESPONSE_TIME":34889}]}}

But strangely, when I change n and batchSize both to 2 and touch nothing else, fetch fetches the first username correctly:

```
fetch(
  myAlias,
  top(
    n=2,
  ....various expressions here
    sort="count(*) desc"
  ),
  fl="username", on="userid=userid", batchSize=2
)
```

Result is:

> {  "result-set":{   "docs":[{
> "userid":"123123",
> "count(*)":58,
> "username":"mura"}    ,{
> "userid":"123123123",
> "count(*)":32,
> "username":"Ayha"}    ,{
> "EOF":true,
> "RESPONSE_TIME":34889}]}}

What can be the problem??

Comment: That sounds like a bug - which version of Solr? Have you tried the `solr-user` mailing list?

Comment: Actually, I think I understood whats going on, albeit accidentally. Let me write that as an answer so maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the reason right after asking, but it took me days to realize this.

I think fetch stream performs a naive "in" query (I saw a similar query in logs while trying to fetch), something like:

> ?q=userid:(123123 123123123 12432423321323)&rows={batchSizeHere}&fl=id,username

When userid to document relation is one-to-many, it is possible that above query will result in documents consisting entirely of last two userid's documents, so the first one is left out, resulting in empty username. Docs state that one to many is not supported with fetch, but I didn't stumble onto this issue until recently so I just assumed it would work. To test my finding, I tried it with batchSize=1 and top=3..top=10 so fetch would perform separate queries for each id, and it successfully found all the usernames. Sadly this trick can't be used when there are many id's to fetch for.

Sorry to take your time, I hope this helps somebody later.